# ¿Como modificar un Label en python3 desde un método o función?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Pues intento modificar el texto de un label llamado "inf" desde un método llamado "get_information" y me sale error, intente con la función "configure" y me sigue saliendo error, como seria la manera correcta de modificarlo?

Con la funcion "configure" me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rrr.py", line 110, in <module>
    r = SystemAppleCore()
  File "rrr.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.get_information()
  File "rrr.py", line 40, in get_information
    inf.configure(text = "Database not generated")
NameError: name 'inf' is not defined
```

Y Cuando intento modificarla normalmente me sale este error:

`typeerror: 'nonetype' object does not support item assignmen`t

> Codigo | Python3:

```
class SystemAppleCore():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Home Schoolers")
        self.database = {}
        self.tell = 0

        Label(self.root, text = "Home Schoolers", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,15)).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 10, padx = 5)

        # Frame
        frame = LabelFrame(self.root, text = " Menu of options ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5)

        # Frame Inf
        self.frameMessage = LabelFrame(self.root, text = " Information ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        self.frameMessage.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 8, padx = 5, sticky = W + E)

        inf = Label(self.frameMessage, text = "").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 5)

        # Buttons
        Button(frame, text = "Options of AppleCores", command = self.optionsAppleCores).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W + E, pady = 3, padx = 5)
        Button(frame, text = "Create AppleCore", command = self.createAppleCore).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W +E, pady = 3, padx = 5)
        Button(frame, text = "Exit", command = lambda:self.root.destroy()).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W +E, pady = 3, padx = 5)

        self.get_information()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_information(self):  
        try:
            open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb").close()
            inf["text"] = "Generated database"

        except:
            inf.configure(text = "Database not generated")

    def accessAppleCore(self):
        pass

    def createAppleCore(self):
        window = Toplevel()
        window.resizable(False, False)

        text = StringVar()

        frame = LabelFrame(window, text = " Create AppleCore ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)

        # AppleCore input
        Label(frame, text = "Name-AppleCore:").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 7, padx = 4)
        name = Entry(frame, textvariable = text).grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 7, padx = 4)

        # Message
#       message = Label(window, text = "dawda").grid(row  = 1, column = 0, sticky = W + E)

        def create(name_AppleCore):
            try:
                with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb") as file:
                    self.database = pickle.load(file)
            except:
                pass

            if name_AppleCore != "":        
                self.database[name_AppleCore] = {

                    "Notes": [],
                    "Assistance": []
                }

                with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "wb") as file:
                    pickle.dump(self.database, file)

                window.destroy()
                self.get_information()

            else:
#               message["text"] = "| Name-AppleCore is required |"
                pass

        # Button
        Button(frame, text = "Add AppleCore", command = lambda:create(text.get())).grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

    def optionsAppleCores(self):
        try:
            with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb") as file:
                self.database = pickle.load(file)

            window = Toplevel()
            window.resizable(False, False)

            frame = LabelFrame(window, text = " AppleCores ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
            frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5)

            for appleCore in self.database.keys():
                self.tell += 1
                Checkbutton(frame, text = "AppleCore: " + appleCore, font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12)).grid(row = self.tell, column = 0, pady = 3, padx = 5, sticky = W)   

        except:
            pass # mensaje aquiii
```

> De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que ya encontré el problema

> 1.- Dejé estas líneas por separado. Cuando configuras la posición del control en la misma línea en que lo defines, éste ya no devuelve un objeto, sino que un **None**

```
self.inf = Label(self.frameMessage, text = "")
self.inf.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 5)
```

> 2.- Luego, cambié el **inf** por **self.inf**, en la declaración, y luego dentro de la función **get_information(self)**.

Reescribí el código con las correcciones para que sea más fácil copiar, pegar y ejecutar.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, LabelFrame, W, E
class SystemAppleCore():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Home Schoolers")
        self.database = {}
        self.tell = 0

        Label(self.root, text = "Home Schoolers", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,15)).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W, pady = 10, padx = 5)

        # Frame
        frame = LabelFrame(self.root, text = " Menu of options ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5)

        # Frame Inf
        self.frameMessage = LabelFrame(self.root, text = " Information ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        self.frameMessage.grid(row = 2, column = 0, pady = 8, padx = 5, sticky = W + E)

        self.inf = Label(self.frameMessage, text = "")
        self.inf.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 5)

        # Buttons
        Button(frame, text = "Options of AppleCores", command = self.optionsAppleCores).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W + E, pady = 3, padx = 5)
        Button(frame, text = "Create AppleCore", command = self.createAppleCore).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W +E, pady = 3, padx = 5)
        Button(frame, text = "Exit", command = lambda:self.root.destroy()).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W +E, pady = 3, padx = 5)

        self.get_information()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_information(self):
        try:
            open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb").close()
            self.inf["text"] = "Generated database"

        except:
            self.inf.configure(text = "Database not generated")

    def accessAppleCore(self):
        pass

    def createAppleCore(self):
        window = Toplevel()
        window.resizable(False, False)

        text = StringVar()

        frame = LabelFrame(window, text = " Create AppleCore ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)

        # AppleCore input
        Label(frame, text = "Name-AppleCore:").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 7, padx = 4)
        name = Entry(frame, textvariable = text).grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 7, padx = 4)

        # Message
#       message = Label(window, text = "dawda").grid(row  = 1, column = 0, sticky = W + E)

        def create(name_AppleCore):
            try:
                with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb") as file:
                    self.database = pickle.load(file)
            except:
                pass

            if name_AppleCore != "":        
                self.database[name_AppleCore] = {

                    "Notes": [],
                    "Assistance": []
                }

                with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "wb") as file:
                    pickle.dump(self.database, file)

                self.get_information()
                #window.destroy()


            else:
#               message["text"] = "| Name-AppleCore is required |"
                pass

        # Button
        Button(frame, text = "Add AppleCore", command = lambda:create(text.get())).grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

    def optionsAppleCores(self):
        try:
            with open("AppleCoreDatabase", "rb") as file:
                self.database = pickle.load(file)

            window = Toplevel()
            window.resizable(False, False)

            frame = LabelFrame(window, text = " AppleCores ", font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12))
            frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5)

            for appleCore in self.database.keys():
                self.tell += 1
                Checkbutton(frame, text = "AppleCore: " + appleCore, font=("Comic Sans MS" ,12)).grid(row = self.tell, column = 0, pady = 3, padx = 5, sticky = W)   

        except:
            pass # mensaje aquiii
SystemAppleCore()
```

Comment: Ya lo intente y no funciona, hay alguna manera mas, para hacerlo?

Comment: Si! Funciona, Gracias!!